# Python mock: replace function with another function if sys.argv argument is set

Tags: python, mocking, arguments, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

I have a snippet of code that looks like this:

```
if args.module == 'omega':
    with mock.patch.object(quantum_entangler, 'sort_by_dirac', sort_by_heisenberg):
        quantum_entangler.main(atom_no)
else:
    quantum_entangler.main(atom_no)
```

Which basically lets me set sort function with `--module` option in the command line call.

I was wondering if there's a way to implement this with just the `mock.patch.object()` line without the if/else block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can use a dictionary of references to the sorting function

The idea is to create a dictionary which contains references to the sorting functions.

The following code is found in a file called `test.py`. To execute `test.py` I have to pass it 2 arguments by command line:

- `--module` with one of the value `omega` | `dirac`
  **NOTE.** I have defined the value `dirac` to execute the normal sorting by the function *sort_by_dirac()*, while by `omega` is selected the sorting by the function *sort_by_heisenberg()* as you already do in your code
- `--atom_no` which can be of any value (it is used to pass something to *main()* function of the module `quantum_entangler.py`):

Code of `test.py`:

```
from unittest import mock
import argparse
import quantum_entangler
from quantum_entangler import sort_by_heisenberg, sort_by_dirac

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--module")
parser.add_argument("--atom_no")
args = parser.parse_args()

atom_no = args.atom_no

# THIS IS THE DICTIONARY of references
sortFunction = {'omega': sort_by_heisenberg, 'delta': sort_by_dirac}

# ---> here you find patch.object() function WITHOUT if/else as you request
# in the question
with mock.patch.object(quantum_entangler,'sort_by_dirac',sortFunction[args.module]):
    quantum_entangler.main(atom_no)
```

### Execution of *test.py*

To test the code I have written a module `quantum_entangler.py` with the following 3 functions:

```
def sort_by_dirac(atom_no):
    print(f"execute sort_by_dirac({atom_no})")
    
def sort_by_heisenberg(atom_no):
    print(f"execute sort_by_heisenberg({atom_no})")
    
def main(atom_no):
    sort_by_dirac(atom_no)
```

Execution of `test.py` with `--module dirac`:

```
python test.py --atom_no 10 --module dirac

# output
execute sort_by_dirac(10)
```

Execution of `test.py` with `--module omega`:

```
python test.py --atom_no 10 --module omega

# output
execute sort_by_heisenberg(10)
```

Answer (score 2):

Fully aware that this is out-of-scope for the current question, but:

If you have the capacity to influence the API of the `quantum_entangler.main` function, it might make it both easier to reason-about and easier to test if you make that function a parameter of `main` instead of trying to patch it in.

Borrowing some of the scaffolding code from the poster above, this could look like:

```py
import argparse

def sort_by_heisenberg(atom_no):
    ...

def sort_by_dirac(atom_no):
    ...

def main(atom_no, sort_fn = sort_by_dirac):
    print(f"executing {sort_fn.__name__}({atom_no})")
    sort_fn(atom_no)


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--module")
parser.add_argument("--atom-no")
args = parser.parse_args()

sort_fn = sort_by_heisenberg if args.module == "omega" else sort_by_dirac

main(args.atom_no, sort_fn)
```

With this as the result:

```
/ # python file.py --atom-no 10
executing sort_by_dirac(10)
/ # python file.py --atom-no 10 --module omega
executing sort_by_heisenberg(10)
```

A benefit to that is that it wouldn't be a breaking change for anyone currently consuming the API, and is easier to debug since otherwise it wouldn't be clear that the sorting function could be different under different contexts

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like:

```
sort_function = sort_by_heisenberg if args.module == 'omega' else sort_by_dirac

with mock.patch.object(quantum_entangler, 'sort_by_dirac', sort_function):
    quantum_entangler.main(atom_no)
```